# How do I look up values in a dataframe and return matching values using python/pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, merge, lookup

I have 2 large dataframes, df1 and df2. I am missing a column (colB) in df2 and I would like to add that column based of the values in the shared column (colA). If I was using Excel I would do this via a standard vlookup formula but I’m struggling to get the desired results using the pandas merge function.

colA and colB both contain multiple entries of the same value so I’m using this line of code to create a new dataframe with only the unique pairings.

```
df_keyvalues = df1[["colA", "colB"]].drop_duplicates()
```

I’m then using merge to add colB into df2

```
df2 = df2.merge(df_keyvalues, how = "left", on = "colA")
```

After running the above, I do get colB in df2 but I also get more row in my dataframe that what I started with.

What am I doing wrong?

I would like to be able to lookup the value in df2[“colA”] in df1[“colA”] and return the value in df1[“colB”]. If the values in df2[“colA”] and df1[“colA”] is not an exact match, then leave value in df2[“colB”] empty and move on to the next one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1 -Check if you still have duplicates in df_keyvalues. When you drop duplicates on two columns sometimes doesn’t works properly.  2 - check if you have duplicates in df2.  3 - isn’t a ‘inner’ join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting more rows after the merge, this means that `colA` is not a unique key of `df_keyvalues`. This in turn means that the mapping `colA -> colB` is not unique in `df1`, i.e. for at least one value of `colA` there are multiple values of `colB`.

You need to create a unique mapping `colA -> colB` from `df1` first. One way to do this would be:

```py
# take the smallest value if A->B mapping is not unique
df_AtoB = df1.groupby("colA", as_index=False).agg(colB_=("colB", "min"))
```

What exactly is the "right" way to de-duplicate above depends on your use-case.

Afterwards you can fill-in `colB` in `df2` as follows

```py
df = df2.merge(df_AtoB, on="colA", how="left")
df.colB = df.colB.fillna(df.colB_)
df = df.drop(columns="colB_")
```